# Cross-Platform API for PaaS vendors?

Tags: api, interop, cross-platform, cloud, paas

Are there any efforts or products out there that aim at a generic API for PaaS vendors?
Similar to cross-platform APIs for IaaS offerings like Delta Cloud, DMTF Cloud Infrastructure Management Interface (CIMI), Simple Cloud, OCCI, ...

Answer (score 2):

AppScale duplicates the App Engine API.

Answer (score 1):

OCCI v. 1.2, which is to be released shortly, has a *Platform* specification, which introduces OCCI classes `Application`, `Component` and `ComponentLink`.

The release will surely be announced at http://occi-wg.org/